# Good approach to interface with database through gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

What I am doing is I create stored procedures for each table for select/insert/update, then I (if select) fill datatable with all the rows and pass to objectdatasource which is bound with gridview. Is it good or bad technique? What are the good techniques (using BO, BL, DAL) to update/remove/insert records in the database through gridviews?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I do a data model layer which encapsulates all data that I want exposed to the main application. I then have a buisiness logic layer which connects the model layer to the Data Access Layer. The data access layer is where all of the magic happens. In here, I use the System.Data, System.Data.SqlClient or MySQL.Data.MySQLClient (or whatever you use--it has a .NET connector) namespaces to actually call the stored procedures and put the data into the data model or vice versa.

Here is an example of one I have done as I explained, but I do mine a little different. I like my data model to actually expose the access methods, it helps with organization of the data. Also, I use the System.Data.DataTable for binding data to the gridview. It works wonderfully and even allows you store primary key and foreign key information. It will manage passing schema information to the gridview for you.

```
public class ImageListModel
{
    private ImageListBLL objImageListBLL; 

    public ImageListModel(string connectionString, string databaseEngine, int groupID)
    {
        if(databaseEngine.ToLower() == "mysql")
            objImageListBLL = new ImageListBLL(DatabaseEngine.MySQL, connectionString);
        GroupID = groupID;
    } 

    public int GroupID
    {
        get;
        set;
    } 

    public DataTable GetImageList()
    {
        return objImageListBLL.GetImageList(GroupID);
    } 

    public bool InsertImage(ImageModel objImage)
    {
        objImage.GroupID = GroupID;
        return objImage.Insert();
    } 

    public bool DeleteImage(ImageModel objImage)
    {
        return objImage.Delete();
    } 

    public bool EditImage(ImageModel objImage)
    {
        return objImage.Edit();
    }
} 

public class ImageModel
{
    private ImageBLL objImageBLL;

    public ImageModel(string connectionString, string databaseEngine)
    {
        if (databaseEngine.ToLower() == "mysql")
            objImageBLL = new ImageBLL(DatabaseEngine.MySQL, connectionString);

    } 

    public long ID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }



    public string TitleTop
    {
        get;
        set;
    } 

    public string TitleBottom
    {
        get;
        set;
    }



    public string ImageUrl
    {
        get;
        set;
    } 

    public string ExtraMarkup
    {
        get;
        set;
    } 

    public string DescriptionUrl
    {
        get;
        set;
    } 

    public int Order
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    public int UserID
    {
        get;
        set;
    } 

    public int GroupID
    {
        get;
        set;
    } 

    public bool Insert()
    {
        return objImageBLL.InsertImage(this);
    } 

    public bool Edit()
    {
        return objImageBLL.EditImage(this);
    } 

    public bool Delete()
    {
        return objImageBLL.DeleteImage(this);
    } 

    public void ChangePosition()
    {
        objImageBLL.ChangeImagePosition(this);
    }
}
```

As you see, the DAL is completely hidden. The BLL manages calling the appropriate data access layer methods. This models a generic list of images with appropriate data state manipulation, retrieving, and saving methods. This is what modeling should mean in my opinion.

I assume you know the nuts and bolts of how to use a db connector. Let me know if you don't and I will post some more code.

My model works as follows:

```
               DataModel -- Exposed to main application
                 |
                 |
                \/
           Business Logic Layer
                 |
              pass DataModel
                 |
                \/
            Data Access Layer
```

Comment: Do you need to have an inheritance for objects with foreign keys? Or This sentence does not make any sense?

Comment: I usually don't let it get that complicated. A simple way to think about it is to think about the objects you will be dealing with in your grid view. Each object will have several members with a simple datatype like string or int. I store all id's and foreign keys for that object in the class. You then can either write methods inside your datamodel to update, insert, and delete records based on the current state of the object (my preffered method) or you can just store data in your datamodel and pass it to the BLL and let it publicly expose your update, insert, etc... You can link objects ...

Comment: together the old fashioned way, with a reference in your datamodel. So, for instance if I have an Order, I may have A customer and an item associated with that orderID, so the Order Data model will have a Customer and an Item instance which stores the data for that record. I find that in a simple Datamodel, linking keeps things much more sane than inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is a good way for basic CRUD functions with a gridview (This might be all you need!). Anything more fancy you might consider using an ORM (Object-Relational Mapping) tool to make business objects that you can play around with.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of CRUD operations through BO, without using ORM? I mean code example.

Comment: You can [build your own active record using the Enterprise Library Data Access Application Block](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/06/11/2985.aspx). Remember any frameworks, library, tools that we suggest are HELPING you to get the end result FASTER. You can always build your own data access layer from ADO.NET 1.0 if you want. In my opinion, finding applications, tools, libraries, patterns to get the job done is better than writing your own code. Because coding is hard, maintaining code is hard, testing code is hard.....

Answer (score 0):

Using ADO.NET Entity Data Models please, it's very simple!

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Requirements do not allow me to use ADO.NET

Comment: Anyone correct me if I am wrong but if you are using .Net, then you must be using ADO.NET to access database, there's no other way. But there are different versions of ADO.NET. ObjectDataSource is from ADO.NET 2.0 and Entity framework is ADO.NET 3.5.

Comment: @Thomas I think you are right. @user194076 I believe the System.Data... namespaces = ADO.NET. Not using ADO.NET for your actual data access is foolish in a C#.NET application unless someone has written an even more easy to use Microsoft supported data access method. If some manager is telling you otherwise, find a new place to work.

Comment: @Thomas There are always other ways. I mean, all a connector is is a damn library sending messages to a remote api via sockets. Anyhow, ADO.NET is always the way to go. Does OLEDB count as ADO.NET? COM had a ton of different data access methods. ADO.NET just turns out to be the best fit for .NET. If you wanted you could always do some COM interop or write wrappers around the native api's. Why someone would want to do that, I don't know.

Comment: @Jonathan Henson Or make yourself an executable using 0's and 1's and feed them to the CPU. It's all about level of abstraction. ^_^